# Java Using the Scanner to write user input to a .txt file

Tags: java

So I am supposed to write a program that reads strings from the user and writes them to an output file, and stop processing when the user inputs "DONE." This is all I have and I'm totally stuck. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Parrish_A04Q3 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        String file = "userStrings.txt";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read from the input and write it into a file.

First point you need a loop for reading the input and condition to terminate. As and when you read the line you can write it into the output file.

```
    String file = "userStrings.txt";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter("\\n");
    System.out.println("Enter DONE to terminate");
    try (PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new File(file))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = scan.nextLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                System.out.println("Exiing");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        fw.println(line);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MaxByTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
String file = "userStrings.txt";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
while(true){
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if("DONE".equalsIgnoreCase(input.trim())){
        break;
    }
    fw.write(input);
}
scan.close();
fw.close();
```